# The First Polymerase

Tags: genetics

Knowing that polymerase protein is needed for the transcription of genes, which polymerase is used in the transcription of polymerase protein itself?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are enquiring about the evolution of RNA polymerase, or about the different RNA polymerases (I, II and III) in contemporary higher organisms.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What came first? The DNA or the DNA polymerases?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/what-came-first-the-dna-or-the-dna-polymerases)

Answer (score 0):

In eukaryotes its RNA polymerase II. In bacteria it is the normal RNA polymerase. Although it is true that polymerases are now needed transcription of more polymerases, this mechanism may not have always been present. In the RNA world hypothesis, RNA coded for proteins and not DNA, so with the emergence of DNA, RNA polymerases may have formed as well. To produce proteins from RNA, organisms use complexes called ribosomes, which are ribozymes (RNA enzymes), which have undergone many rounds of evolution from original ribosomes, so there wasn't an issue with the production of proteins from RNA and throughout the course of evolution, polymerases were then developed, but they were only necessary with the rise of DNA.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. I suspect it's the old chestnut of the chicken and the egg. And even in an RNA world, polymerase (RNA-dependent RNA polymerase) must have developed very early — certainly before ribosomes, as these were only needed to make protein. The answer would seem to be that there was non-enzymic methods of RNA replication, followed by a ribozyme-like enzyme. Whether protein RNA replicases developed before DNA came on the scene is a moot point.

Comment: I dont know if we have a solution as to how functional RNAs were first formed. I have found a polymerase that was rationally developed for RNA polymerisation, although the paper is unsure as to whether this was feasible DOI: 10.1126/science.1060786. if you know of any research that has gotten any further please let me know!

Comment: I prefer a link I can tap on, especially on the phone. I’ll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. I checked out the RNA World Hypothesis, it is very interesting, though it is a shame that some scientists were criticizing it.

Comment: Oh the cell has premade RNA polymerase from the mother's egg cells

Comment: @user3742855 Criticism is good and experiments are even better. Both proving and falsifying a hypothesis increase scientific knowledge.